# CC2520/ATtiny861A pin configuration

Tags: microcontroller, avr, attiny, pins

I am looking to hook up a radio with an ATtiny861A microcontroller. The radio that I will be using is the CC2520 from Texas Instruments. The RESETn pin(on the CC2520) will allow me to put my circuit into a sleep mode and this requires me to have the reset pin attached to the MCU(The datasheet says that I could reset it through SPI but I want to know if I can use one of the pins that I have left over). The RESETn Pin says it is a TBOUTH/SVSOUT. Leftover on my 861A MCU I have pin 4 which is OC1B/PCint11, pin 17 which is AREF/PCINT3, and pin 9 which is ADC9/INT0/T0/PCINT14. Am I able to connect any of these pins to the RESETn from the CC2520 radio? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CC2520 datasheet it looks like all you need to do is control the resetn of the CC2520 with any GPIO pin. As long as you can drive the pin high and low you should be fine. Any of those pins should work provided they are configured as outputs.

I might consider adding an external pullup resistor on that resetn line if you don't want the CC2520 to be reset when the MCU gets reset, otherwise it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Configuring the pins as outputs would all be within the software, correct?

Comment: Yup, the DDR(insert register here) command will set bits as an input or an output. For example, say I want to set bits 5 and 6 on PORTD on an AVR to output. I would use the following code:                 DDRD |= (1 << 5) | (1 << 6);

Comment: I agree.  Any GPIO should work.  About the only thing I'd change is a pull-down resistor, so that device is reset and power down from power up. (But that's just me)

Comment: Are the AREF/PCINT pins all GPIO pins?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to read your datasheet (http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2588-8-bit-AVR-Microcontrollers-tinyAVR-ATtiny261-ATtiny461-ATtiny861_Datasheet.pdf) to figure out how to configure them as GPIO as opposed to AREF. Also are you doing any ADC? If so I wouldn't mess with AREF

Comment: I have three pins "leftover" for a CS/SS as well as the RESETn pin from the CC2520. Leftover I have pin 4(OC1B/PCINT11), pin 9(ADC9/INT0/T0/PCINT14), and pin 17(AREF/PCINT13). I would like to use the CS/SS with pin 9 that has the ADC, but I still need to have a pin for the RESETn from the CC2520.

Comment: Those three pins should work for each of your functions. Just read over how to enable standard GPIO for them (the only one I think you have to change is the AREF pin, look at the DIDR0 register in the datasheet)

Comment: Would it be easier to just use pin 4(OC1B/PCINT11) as the RESETn and have pin 17(AREF/PCINT3) connected to a pullup/down resistor?

Comment: You need two separate GPIO pins for the two CS/SS lines. If you really wanted to use pin4 as the RESETn line, you will need to use pin9 and pin17 as the two CS/SS lines. When using pin17 you will have to make sure it is properly configured as GPIO when you initialize it. I'm not sure what you mean by having pin17 connected to a pullup/down resistor

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I have three pins open and I have two things to fill them with. I need to put one pin as a chip select and another as the RESETn. This will leave me with one open pin.

Comment: Yeah in that case I wouldn't use the Aref pin and use the other two instead